# My font differs in chrome browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a website, which is a internet forum, and in my forum posts, I have the following font:

```
font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

Now, here's how it looks like in different browsers: (from left: chrome, firefox, IE)

[image: chrome font diff]

As you can see, chrome is displaying whole different font than the other two. Why? How do I fix that (I want this font to look like the other two)? Also, this is the link to the page I made screenshot of: https://scyk.pl/Forums/Thread/Na%20luzie/8 (look at the post contents)

Comment: You can use web fonts and load the font explicitly.

Comment: Are you using a font-face? or Google fonts? If not chrome most likely doesn't have that font you are using so it is using one of your fall backs. `Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif` = fallbacks

Comment: You can use @font-face to explicitly load the font you want to use

Comment: You should include code that reproduces the problem, in the question itself. Besides, the URL specified does not (currently) demonstrate the problem: the text looks basically the same on Chrome as on other browsers, and different from the screenshot. And there are 43 Errors, 17 warnings reported when I submit the page to http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that Google Chrome most likely does not have that font, and is using the fall back fonts instead. To make sure this doesn't happen, you can explicitly load the font using

> @font-face

in CSS3, which allows you to explicitly load the fonts by referencing it. You can learn more about using @font-face [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp), where you use src: and get the url of whatever font you are using.

If the font is not that important, however, I recommend not worrying about it and just letting Chrome use the fallback fonts instead.

To do @font-face, the code would be:

```
@font-face {
font-family:Segoe UI;
src:url(https://github.com/shawnphoffman/shawnphoffman.com/blob/master/Content/fonts/segoe-ui-semilight.woff);
}
```

You may have to go to the github link and download the raw version of the font, then reference it there.

Comment: If you do that, make sure you have the license to do so. Failing that, automated scrapers can locate and sue you.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options but I think you'll find all of them unsatisfactory:

- Render the page into an image on the server and send that to the client.
- Get the source code for Chrome and replace the font rendering engine with the one used by Firefox.

Oh, btw, it will also look different on Safari (probably a lot different to the other three; Safari is a very sophisticated browser and it will try it's utmost to make a page look good; driving web designers insane in the process is a small price to pay for beauty ;-)).

Rendering text is something that you only have limited control over. Maybe Chrome doesn't find  `Segoe UI`, maybe the font rendering engine can't use the hinting of your font. While not ideal, I suggest not to spend too much time on it.